# using the command line prompt in Java Eclipse

Tags: java

I am trying to learn how to use the Java Command Line input in Eclipse.

I have a very simple method that prints out a name.

How would I change this method so that from the command line input in Java Eclipse I can run the main method and put in different names to print?

If I can understand this I can then go forward and try something more complex.

Thank you in advance

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("cosmo");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?  SO generally likes to see some effort put into solving the problem yourself before asking others for help.  I would start by reading about how to create a BufferedReader off the system input stream then reading from it to get your value.

Comment: Note: "in Eclipse" shouldn't matter since all IDEs will run your code similarly

Comment: I have tried everything myself - I am very selective in the questions I ask - but when you are trying to reskill yourself in new IT skills there is always a basic concept that once overcome opens the door to more progress......

Comment: Perhaps you should include in your question what you tried (including searching for similar questions)